# Why does VSCode constantly mess up my Flutter code with weird identation?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I save my Dart files in VSCode, it often messes their identation in weird ways, Now, I already remember it creating new lines when coding in JS, but at least that was unnoticable. But here? It looks this:

```dart
        body: screens[
            currentIndex]
```

and this:

```dart
class RemotePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: [
        Row(children: [
          PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Row(children: [
                      Iconify(AkarIcons.youtube_fill),
                      Text("YouTube")
                    ]))
                  ])
        ])
      ]));
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this happens, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

It's the trailing commas and the 80 column size.
In Dart, you don't have a problem if you put a trailing comma, in fact, in Flutter this is suggested that you do to fix these indentation issues.
How your code would be:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                PopupMenuButton(
                  itemBuilder: (context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Iconify(AkarIcons.youtube_fill),
                          Text("YouTube"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

About the 80 column size, it is on the Dart settings for VSCode, but this is suggested as all Flutter/Dart projects use this.

#### Suggestion

Maybe try and activate the Analizer linter [require_trailing_commas](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/require_trailing_commas.html)

Comment: Do you know how to activate it? I can't for the life of me figure out how! Maybe it's not available yet cause it's experimental.

Comment: This tutorial might help https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: I already saw this page and it didn't really help. But I also have good news: I found the setting that caused all this! It's the `dart-style` package. I disabled it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please vote for my answer or at least publish your own and mark it as the solution? Other people might have the same problem, so you'll help them. Thank you!

Comment: Okay! I'm still relatively new to this site, so I have to get the hand of it all,